# The best way to run a function that needs to run every 24 hours at a specific time

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

What is the best way to handle a function that needs to run every 24 hours at a specific time?

let's say we have an application that pays people for a service that they provide during the day. we already stored the amount of work they did for the day and it's time to pay up.

we want the system to automatically pay (let's assume we toke care of this) them every day at 00:00.

what is the best way to do this?

I'm planning to ask the backend to calculate the remaining time to 00:00. then run our payment function after that time and that function runs itself every 24 hours

A: Is this a good way to handle things? & Is it scaleable?

B: What is the best way to do it in node.js? (I know how to work with the node built-in functions, but I'm not that great with algorithms I'm not sure if using setInterval is ok or not)

ps: other questions suggested using corn jobs that I'm already familiar with, I'm not looking to use any package I'm trying to do it by myself. in fact, I know how to do it myself, I'm just trying to know what is the best way to do it. this is not a project that I want to do for a client. this is a practice.

Comment: This seems too opinion based for Stackoverflow, but you aren't doing yourself any favours trying to write a task scheduler from scratch instead of using an existing one.

Comment: @Quentin this project is a practice of creating the job scheduler.

Comment: @kouroshtajalliepour Unfortunately, that was not clear from your question. Title, body and tags all suggest you are developing a (scheduled) backend application, not a job scheduler. Please rephrase your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a function every X time or at a specific time, you should check cron jobs.

You have multiple ways to handle cron jobs. If you want to deploy a "quick" PoC, you can check websites (like easy cron) that permits you to call a URL (and by extension a function) with a cron expression (everyday, every month, etc...).

Or you can use some node packages, you will find on the npm index.

Comment: I'm familiar with cron jobs, I'm not looking to use any package I'm trying to do it by myself. in fact, I know how to do it myself, I'm just trying to know what is the best way to do it. this is not a project that I want to do for a client. this is practice

Answer (score -1):

Check utilizing cron, cron is a job scheduler. You have many differents options about date,time etc.